# comparing values from top2 select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 2
    ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW,
    ALLOCATIONS_FW.END_DATE_FW,
    ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW,
    ALLOCATIONS_FW.LOCATION_CODE_FW,
    ALLOCATIONS_FW.COMPANY_CODE_FW
FROM
    ALLOCATIONS_FW
WHERE
    ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW =
            (SELECT MAX(ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW)
             FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW) AND
    VEHICLE_ID_FW =
            (SELECT VEHICLE_ID_FW
            FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW 
            WHERE ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%) AND
    ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%
```

How can I compare values of top 1 and top 2 from this top2 select statement?

```
VEHICLE_ID_FW|END_DATE_FW|START_DATE_FW|LOCATION_CODE_FW |COMPANY_CODE_FW
ABC123       | //        | 02/15/2016  |    103          |      NAC
ABC123       |02/14/2015 | 01/14/2016  |    100          |      VIC
```

Comment: At first you are missing `ORDER BY` for your `TOP`; filtering by `MAX(START_DATE_FW)` looks like `ORDER BY START_DATE_FW DESC`. And `VEHICLE_ID_FW` filtering may fall in case when subquery returned more than one row. If this subquery returns always a single row then why do you need this predicate at all if you are already filtering by `RECORD_NUMBER_FW` the main query.

Comment: Ms sql and mysql are 2 different products, pls only use the relevant product tag only!